# 06 accord throwing 13 codes suddenly

Tags: honda, accord

Hi my son has an 06 accord. Previously no engine lights. The other day it suddenly wouldn't accelerate and the vsa and blinking d lights came on. We took it to our mechanic and it's throwing 13 different codes. Some that contradict eachother according to our mechanic. The dash also was saying the car was overhearing when he was looking at it but it wasn't overheating. He said he doesn't understand how all of these codes are being thrown and doesn't know where to start. Please help!

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: Which codes contradict each other? You don't need to take the car to a mechanic to see error codes, it would be worthwhile to get an OBDII code reader and check these things yourself. I've tried code readers from OBD Advanced (for less than $10), Innova ($400) and BlueDriver ($90) and found the BlueDriver one to be the best ***by far***. For example see [**this**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/69j0J.png) which is in CAD and will be less in USD.

Answer (score 6):

Check the voltage at the battery. If the voltage is low, it could be enough to start/run the car, but not enough for the electronics, which will throw a ton of stupid codes and dash lights. Voltage when off should be 12.5vdc or better for a normal battery. If it's doing as I'm suggesting, it would probably in the 10.5-11vdc range. When running the vehicle should be producing ~13.5-14vdc.

Comment: Thanks I will suggest that.  Someone else said possibly the throttle body position sensor? I finally got to see the print out of the codes and it's a page full of codes. Previously there were none. I've never seen anything like it and it happened without warning

Comment: I'm doubting the throttle body position sensor (TPS) would have anything to do with it. usually when a TPS goes bad, the engine will run just fine at idle, then once you start trying to accelerate is when it will start running lousy (if the sensor is completely dorked) or it may have cause issues at a certain throttle position (if there's a dead spot in the sensor). I've never seen multiple codes as you've described thrown due to a TPS.